# Object is rotating too slowly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

So basically I "made" a script that controls the hand movement, and has proper collisions too. Most of it works, however, the rotation seems to have a limited speed, even if its speed is set to high values.

The speed of the rotation is slow, no matter what I change the multiplier to.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hand: MonoBehaviour
{
    // Physics Movement
    [SerializeField] private GameObject followObject;
    [SerializeField] private float followSpeed = 30f;
    [SerializeField] private float rotateSpeed = 100f;
    [SerializeField] private float teleportDistance = 0.75f;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 positionOffset;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 rotationOffset;
    private Transform _followTarget;
    private Rigidbody _body;
    private bool _inGrab = false;

    void Start()
    {
        // Physics Movement
        _followTarget = followObject.transform;
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _body.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode.Continuous;
        _body.interpolation = RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate;
        _body.mass = 20f;

        // Teleport Hands
        _body.position = _followTarget.position;
        _body.rotation = _followTarget.rotation;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        PhysicsMove();
    }

    private void PhysicsMove()
    {
        // Position
        var positionWithOffset = _followTarget.position + positionOffset;
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(positionWithOffset, transform.position);
        _body.velocity = (positionWithOffset - transform.position).normalized * (followSpeed * distance);

        // Rotation
        var rotationWithOffset = _followTarget.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(rotationOffset);
        var q = rotationWithOffset * Quaternion.Inverse(_body.rotation);
        q.ToAngleAxis(out float angle, out Vector3 axis);
        _body.angularVelocity = axis * (angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad * rotateSpeed);

        // Teleport back when too far
        if(distance > teleportDistance)
        {
            _body.position = _followTarget.position;
            _body.rotation = _followTarget.rotation;
        }
    }
}
```

The script is attached to a hand model with a rigidbody, and the follow-target is the XR Controller. Everything seems to be working, except the speed of the rotation.

Rarely worked with quaternions, so it might just be some basic issue.

Comment: If you just want it to follow the controller are you sure you want to move it via physics? Seems to me you'd get a better result just using SLerp against the transform.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? If mine was helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) to give me some reputation points and help others browsing the search panel that there is a helpful answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the [`maxAngularVelocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-maxAngularVelocity.html) of the rigidbody. The default is only 7 radians per second, which is less than 2 full rotations per second.

Setting it to something higher, such as 20, will allow your Rigidbody to turn more quickly when needed. Unfortunately, this isn't accessible through the inspector, but it is  through scripting:

```
void Start()
{
    // Physics Movement
    _followTarget = followObject.transform;
    _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    _body.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode.Continuous;
    _body.interpolation = RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate;
    _body.mass = 20f;
    _body.maxAngularVelocity = 20f;

    // Teleport Hands
    _body.position = _followTarget.position;
    _body.rotation = _followTarget.rotation;
}
```